# How to see the pig version installed on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to check the version of PIG installed on my hadoop. How can we see the pig version installed on Hadoop?
Is there any command to see that?

Answer (score 5):

Use `pig --version` to get the version of pig installed

Output would be something like this:

```
Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.1.3 (rexported) 
compiled Sep 16 2014, 20:39:45
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `pig -version` or `pig --version` or `pig -i` from [PIG-13](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-13).

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to get pig version: (on CDH)

pig -i

sample output:
`$ pig -i
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.13.0 (rexported) 
compiled Oct 04 2017, 11:09:03`